# How to implement text list sorting on python, similar to SQL?

Tags: python, sorting

Good afternoon. 
There is a list that returned the SQL request

```
select name from table order by name ASC
old = [
    "22 9",
    "22 9",
    "252",
    "444",
    "5452452",
    "9797",
    "iPhone 7",
    "API AutoTe2017-05-15 17:28:34",
    "API AutoTest Long Name API AutoTest Long Name API AutoTest Long Name API Auto2017-02-01 13:01:51",
    "API AutoTest Long Name API AutoTest Long Name API AutoTest2017-05-30 11:50:44",
    "API AutoTest New Name2017-09-17 15:18:233",
    "API AutoTest2017-01-11 11:14:16",
    "API AutoTest2017-09-28 23:26:33",
    "q1qq 3213123123123 w1ww 123123123123",
    "sony xvlr walkman xvlr",
    "test1 test_model",
    "TM3000 Programmable GPS Asset Tracker",
    "v-1-1-1 m-2-2-2-2",
    "ббб",
    "Новое устрйосвто"
]
```

The goal is to check that the list is sorted (for testing automation)

im make

```
new = sorted(list, reverse=False) 
print old == new
```

An unequal sort is obtained from the query and from the python code.
[result screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGTqN.png)

How to make that sorting was equivalent, thanks?

Comment: (From a test automation perspective) you don't really want to be sorting with an equivalent method - or you're not actually testing the SQL returns a correct sort. What you want is a hand-made list of sorted data to compare with a sql query on test data (to ensure your stored query always returns the expected result). Don't dynamically generate your test data from the data you are testing itself.

Comment: Yes, that's right, unfortunately the autotests got to me in support. We have to work with the fact that there is.

Comment: No worries, that's understandable. Could you post a text version of the two lists you get, just to make it easier to see what the different sorting rules were?